# Error using \cite

Tags: bibliographies

I get the following error when using \cite

```
Runaway argument?
]{morkovin} and \cite {reshotko}, the first who coined the term "Rece\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.27
```

Isn't `\cite{}` the way to cite? The line where the error is:

```
 According to \cite{morkovin} and \cite{reshotko}, the first who coined
```

Update: having a deeper look on the internet, I solved the issue commenting `\usepackage{cite}` in the main file. Now it works!

Comment: you have a missing brace somewhere else (or you have used a fragile command in a moving argument) but it is very hard to tell if you do not post any code that shows the error. But this is unrelated to the first question, so could you edit the title and delete the references to usepackage

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Code snippets are rarely sufficient to be able to diagnose such problems, please post a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: There's not much special about the code, the typical citation. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: @Carlos the thing that is special about the code is that it has an error in a part you have not shown. the error message shows a `]` which is probably part of a command argument and it is the arguments of that earlier command that are wrong,

Comment: @Carlos - "Does anyone know what's going on?" I'm afraid we won't know what's going on until you provide more background information, ideally in the form of a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that produces an error of the type you're looking to fix.

Comment: There is \section{Introduction}, text and more text (no commands invoked until the first \cite{morkovin}

Comment: See my answer which is a _complete_ document that anyone can run and get the error message that you state. If your document is _not_ like that but as you show above really has `\cite{morkovin}` with no `[` then add a similar complete document to your question so we can debug.

Comment: glad you got it working but as it stands this post is no use at all for any readers as you just avoided some error in code you have not shown by removing a package that you had not said that you were using. Please either delete or make it more useful by adding an example like the one I showed that shows how to generate the error and how commenting out cite package avoids the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3):

You gave very few clues but I would assume that your input is not as you stated but is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

 According to \cite{xx]{morkovin} and \cite{reshotko}, the first who coined

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
Runaway argument?
{xx]{morkovin} and \cite {reshotko}, the first who coined 
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6
```

Comment: Not really!, there is a \cite{morkovin}. Is [] mandatory?

Comment: @Carlos I had to guess as you seem reluctant to show any code, how do you think people can debug code that they can not see?